# How to set the vertical scroll in RichTextFx

Tags: javafx, richtextfx

I want to be able to set the vertical scroll to the top or the bottom of a `InlineStyleTextArea` in [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX). By the looks of [this](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX/issues/130) thread, `moveTo(..)` should do the trick. But it doesn't work for me. I've also tried `selectRange(..)` and `positionCaret(..)`. Below is my test program, have I misunderstood the "workaround of repositioning the caret" mentioned in the thread linked above?

```
import org.fxmisc.richtext.InlineStyleTextArea;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class RichTextFXTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public  void start(Stage stage) {

        InlineStyleTextArea<StyleInfo> area = new InlineStyleTextArea<>(
                new StyleInfo(), styleInfo -> styleInfo.toCss());
                area.setPrefSize(300, 300);
        area.setWrapText(false);
                area.setEditable(false);

                StringBuilder largeText = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
                largeText.append("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n");
                }

                area.replaceText(largeText.toString());

                // None of the two rows below works.
                //area.selectRange(1000, 1100);
                //area.moveTo(1100);
                //area.positionCaret(1100);

                HBox rootLayout = new HBox();
                rootLayout.setPrefSize(300, 300);
                rootLayout.getChildren().add(area);

                Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
     }

     // Style class
        class StyleInfo {
            String toCss() {
                return "-fx-fill: red;
            } 
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
            launch();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tomas Mikula provided the answer in [this](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX/issues/130#issuecomment-146950157) github thread. I thought I'd put the answer here as well.

> The problem with your example is that the moveTo/selectRange
> work-around does not work before the skin is instantiated. If in your
> example you surround the selectRange in Platform.runLater, that will
> give you the desired result. Also note that the range is given in
> character indices, not line numbers.
>
> `Platform.runLater(() -> area.selectRange(10000, 10100));`
>
> In the code
> that results from user's interaction after the text area has already
> been shown, you will not need Platform.runLater anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
int pos = 1100;
area.moveTo(pos);
area.requestFollowCaret();
```